# Software Raid 10 on VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, partition, software-raid, raid10

I want to learn how to use Software Raid 10, is it possible to use VirtualBox by adding four storage images?

This is my plan:

- 4x 100mb partitions (1 on each drive) configured as a raid 1 for /boot in ext3.
- Then with the remaining space on each drive, setup a software raid partition and configure it to to LVM and raid 10.
- In the LVM, set up a 4gb swap partition and the remaining space as the root partition ( / ) as ext3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this will work.  Of course, don't expect to get any performance gain as the underlying disks are on the same device, but it's a great way to learn how to set it up in a safe environment.

Comment: It took me a while to come up with an answer better than "Yes."

Comment: Haha thanks. Will LVM reduce the performance of O/I?

Comment: @Black addressed this point perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

As Kyle said, this will work. The setup and administration tasks
will be identical to a physical system. As additional benefit, You
can simulate the removal and replacement of a disk without fiddling
with five disks.

However:

- There won't be any redundancy. Therefore, Your raid is as vulnerable as the host file system.
- I/O performance will be *very* low. Every write access results in two physical writes on  two different parts of *the same physical disc* on the host system.

Comment: Define 'host system' ?

Comment: 'host system' means the physical system that runs VirtualBox.